# What is the purpose of data types in (Py)Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

PySpark offers various data types, however there does not seem to be any useful method we can call on those types. For example, [`ArrayType` does not even have insert, remove, or find methods](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.types.ArrayType).

Why is this lack of methods? What is the purpose of data types in Spark if we can do nothing to them? How does Spark handle those types internally?

Comment: Types are for describing schemas. You don't insert or read from schemas, they're just metadata. The actual data is somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

The types of Spark are not like objects in default languages. They are for serialization purpose allowing Spark store the data in any format that it supports that are: `json, parquet, orc, csv` and so on, that will allow you to keep the type when you write to your storage.

To have more ways to handle the types, Spark (Scala) allow you to use `DataSets` that you can use `case class` to define your types. Then you can use the primitive types to handle the requests.

```
import spark.implicits._
case class MyData(str1: String, int1: Int, arr1: Array[String])
spark.read.table("my_table").as[MyData]
```

For PySpark this is a little bit more complicated, but you don't need to worry about serialization.

If you need to manipulate the types in the PySpark, you can use the [sql functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#module-pyspark.sql.functions).